# how to install tox as current user?

Tags: python, tox

It seems that there is a problem with installing tox as current user:

I did a `pip install --user tox` and it worked but in this case `tox` command is not installed and the usual trick of running the module via `python -m tox` does not work with tox.

Comment: Which platform and python version are you trying on ? Generally `pip install tox` works flawless on python3.4 and grater.

Answer (score 4):

Check the output of the pip command to see where it installed the tox binary. It's probably just not on your path. On my system, it is installed to `~/.local/bin/tox`:

```
Installing tox script to /home/rene/.local/bin
```

So I can run it like this:

```
~/.local/bin/tox
```

If, for some reason, you want to use the `python -m` way, something like this should work:

```
PYTHONPATH="~/.local/bin" python -m tox
```

Anyway, I suggest you also take a look at [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

Comment: Am I missing something  here, but my impression is that either tox or pip are broken when performing a `pip install --user tox` - when you do this, you endup with broken `tox`. I am talking about default config of Python (on OS X but probably linux too), where the user didn't touch the PYTHONPATH. If I remember, the bin directory was kinda optional, but for tox it seems that it is not. Pytest has no problem with this, even if you do not have the bin, you can always use the python -m approach... which works.